# Is there a way to change the site so that spoliers post are not so in your face?

Tags: discussion

Okay so I know that spoilers are okay on this site and also that text can be hidden so that it's only shown when scrolled over. Regardless of that though when a movie comes out I don't visit this site as often because I can read a question that completely spoils a movie for me just by glancing at the page. Now individually editing the questions to hide spoilers is probably the most basic answer but that requires a lot of effort on moderators. Is there a way to design the site so that spoiler or new release info isn't so in your face. I do also understand that we need these questions and that they can be a huge draw and bring people in so I don't want to discourage spoiler questions I just don't want to be discouraged from watching a movie because I've seen them.

Comment: the only real solution besides the ignore tags option is to teach users to not put blatent spoilers in the question titles.

Comment: This problem only applies for question titles and the only way to solve this is, as *DForck42* already says, to discourage spoilers in question titles. Of course, if you don't want to get the movie spoiled, then **don't read the actual question body**! But spoilers in title can in the end be solved pretty good with ignoring the corresponding tag.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to help prevent questions from spoiling a movie for you is to add the movie's tag to your Ignored tags.  I did this when DKR came out so that it didn't get spoiled for me.

Comment: It should be noted you can do this even with tags that don't exist.

Comment: Thank you. I actually didn't know that I could ignore Tags. I feel silly now but I still think that it's a valid question since the site does hope to attract new users on a regular basis. *Update: the ignore tags button is so obvious to me now I have no idea how I missed it and it's purpose.